# How to characterize an input signal?

Tags: adc, signal-processing, sampling

I'm planning on doing some signal processing on my electric guitar with an MCU and I was wondering how I can characterize my input signal so I know if and what kind of pre-amp/ADC I'd need or if the MCU's ADC would be sufficient for my needs.

Typically when connecting a sensor or working with a known signal, I'd have an idea of the signal's resolution and if I need to use an amplifier, but in this case, I have no clue about the max or the min of the signal and neither by how much it'd change OR how much resolution I need; all I know are the frequencies I care about. I understand that I can just hook up my guitar to an oscilloscope or the MCU's ADC and play around to figure these things out, but are there good theory-driven/best-practice approaches for characterizing (input) signals that one doesn't know much about?

Comment: The professional one is "use an oscilloscope", but they're not cheap.

Comment: @pjc50 I have one, I just wanted to know if there is a better approach on how to do it rather than "throw darts at the board", so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When going into a high impedance input, expect something like 100 mV amplitude while playing normally for a modernish guitar (with sort of loud output) and up to a few Volts of spikes when hitting the strings. Typically you don't lose much fidelity if you don't capture those spikes completely. When the sound is fading away, it reaches down to mVs and below. If you instead have a guitar which is made with a "vintage" sound the pickup output could be easily down to a tenth of the above figures.

A > 20-bit ADC is recommended to have a good resolution on quieter parts.

You could hook it up to your computer and record a bit with some computer oscilloscope software, to get an idea of the amplitudes. But a line-input has a  rather low input impedance, so it will a) load down the guitar signal and b) damp its resonance. So as a result that would show a lower signal level than when recorded using a high impedance input. If available, a dedicated microphone input would be a better choice. Or you could take your guitar signal through a buffer/booster pedal with a gain of 1 and feed that into the PC.

Comment: Computer line level audio input would have completely different characteristics regarding input impedance and signal levels. It would load down the signal very differently compared to an input made specifically o receive guitar signals. PC line input would expect much higher amplitude so looking at signal amplitude received via line on an oscilloscope software would not be a good estimate of the actual signal voltage.

Comment: @Justme True.. I am using a preamplifier in my cable for a long time, so I forgot about the large output impedance. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @tobalt Thank you for your answer! I guess my question was more of if there is a  more theoretical way to find out those values that you mention rather than just record a waveform and go from there, but I'll go ahead and just do that :)

Comment: @NickStpn there really isn't Im afraid. It depends on many things that are hard to capture theoretically, like the string composition, strength of attack, pickup distance, magnet type, and even to some extent on the guitar body build...Besides all the electric parameters of the pickup and cabling.